# Multiple conditions need to be met using if statements in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Can I have multiple conditions in an if statement using jQuery? The following code is not catching the errors at all. 
made edits per posted suggestions

```
 $('.goRedIMG').on('click',function(event){
        var ischecked = false;
        var isOKtoSubmit = true;
        var alertMessage = 'No tools have been selected';
        var statusvar = '';
        var transferstatusvar = '';
        var action = $('#uTransaction option:selected').html();

        $('.chkaction').each(function() { //loop through each checkbox
            statusvar = $(this).closest('tr').children('.recordStatus').html();
            transferstatusvar = $(this).closest('tr').children('.transferstat').html()

            if($(this).prop('checked')) {
                ischecked = true;
                if((action == 'Transfer' && statusvar != 'ACTIVE') || (transferstatusvar != 'OK')){             
                    isOKtoSubmit = false;
                    alertMessage = 'One or more records cannot be transferred because status is not ACTIVE and transfer status is not OK';           
                }                  
            }
            if(action == 'Accept Transfer' && transferstatusvar != 'AWAITING'){                
                    isOKtoSubmit = false;
                    alertMessage = 'One or more records cannot be accepted or rejected because status is not ACTIVE or Transfer Status is not AWAITING';                    
                }              
       });
    if(isOKtoSubmit && ischecked !== false && action !== '--Select One--'){                 
            $('#toolActions').submit();         
        }else {
            alert(alertMessage);
        }       
    });
```

Comment: Please remove ; from the end of the 'if' statement. 'If' statements do not have ; at the end

Answer (score 4):

When you're using `&&` (AND) and `||` (OR) in the same if argument, you need to group them.

So instead of this:

```
if(action == 'Transfer' && statusvar !== 'ACTIVE' || (transferstatusvar !== 'OK'))
```

You should do:

```
if((action == 'Transfer' && statusvar != 'ACTIVE') || (transferstatusvar != 'OK'))
```

(Also, you don't need `!==` when you want to check if not equals, you do `!=` instead)

Comment: that worked for the first if but the next one is not working.:
    if(action == 'Accept Transfer' && transferstatusvar != 'AWAITING'){             
               isOKtoSubmit = false;
               alertMessage = 'One or more records cannot be accepted or rejected because status is not ACTIVE or Transfer Status is not AWAITING'; 
              
          }

Comment: You need to use the same logic on all of your arguments.  If it worked, please accept the answer.

Comment: I edited my code with the posted suggestions. The second if statement is not being recognized.

Comment: I did not ask you to code it for me I asked what was wrong with the second if statement. The second if statement just has an && in it and not and && and an ||. If you are going to be like that then don't post suggestions. I code daily and I ran into a problem. I understand structure I am just stuck.